# How to set up TPLink WR941HP as slave router with guest network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I am trying to set up routers around my place to have wi-fi coverage and security..

Here is the situation: I live with my family in a moderately large property, so in order to have complete wi-fi coverage we need couple of routers to ensure signal strength. Also, we have spare rooms [we rent through airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com.br/rooms/17492554?guests=1&adults=1), so we have a dual band tplink wr941hp router in order to have a guest wi-fi network set up.
Finally, our ISP provides a weak wi-fi router (default IP 192.168.1.254) which we are trying to work around.

What I am trying to do: I have the ISP router wi-fi turned off. TPLink is set as slave: lan-to-lan from the ISP to the TPLink; TPLink DHCP turned off; TPLink IP set to 192.168.1.50 (as per [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZVIoj8A8Po)). Main SSID is the family wi-fi, and a guest wi-fi SSID set-up.

Problem is, I am unable to connect to the guest wi-fi.
I get internet just fine though the family wi-fi, but guest is unable to resolve IP from what I was able to gather (I tried connecting with my laptop and phone. On the android phone, connection stalls at "Getting IP address..." and than fails).

Edit: router info as [requested by Tim_Stewart](https://superuser.com/questions/1404438/how-to-set-up-tplink-wr941hp-as-slave-router-with-guest-network?noredirect=1#comment2118540_1404438)

TPLink WR941HP v2.0
firmware: 2.0.1 build 20180305 Rel. 54795(4252)

[Guest WLAN config page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Hm4.png)

Can I get some help with this?

Comment: Hi @Tim_Stewart, thanks to your commentI seem to have fixed the issue. Since you asked for an image of my guest WLAN configuration page, I assumed something there could have been misconfiged and tried ticking the box on the second line, that read "allow guests to access my local network". I am now able to connect and have internet through guest wi-fi. But I thought that this would compromise my family network security. I noticed I cannot login to the TPLink router from the guest wi-fi.. so maybe I was overzealous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. from [@Tim_Stewart's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1404438/how-to-set-up-tplink-wr941hp-as-slave-router-with-guest-network?noredirect=1#comment2118540_1404438) I was able to find the necessary configuration to get my guest wi-fi working as expected.

On the Guest WLAN page, you have two checkboxes with options:

```
1 - Allow guests to see each other
2 - Allow guests to access my local network
```

Ticking the second box has resolved the issue of not being able to connect to the guest wi-fi.

Since I remain unable to access router through guest wi-fi, I am inclined to believe this is not actually exposing my family network to guests, like i thought it would.